# Having difficulty installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my old Ibm Thinkpad T43

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad

While trying to install ubuntu 14.04 on my old Ibm Thinkpad T43 it can freeze anytime from the Ubuntu logo screen right up to the installing of the file screens. One time while running the live trial it worked for well over 45 mins. no problem. Should I be using a different version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Describe the freeze in detail.  Does it completely lock up, with no mouse movement?  Or does it just not respond to input?  Did you spill your coffee on it recently?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Lubuntu? Older hardware usually performs much better with Lubuntu as it is better optimized for such hardware. If not I'd really recommend it. See if the same thing occurs in Lubuntu.

Comment: Tried reinstalling this morning and it actually worked. Just switched on and the computer is going through some Memtest86. waiting to see what happens next?

Comment: @RaymondSmith Huh. Weird. Maybe just a fluke?